# How do I establish a connection with the 2007 Published Project Server database? And download all projects with their milestones?

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, project, psi

I am working on a project to creates KPIs based on project data within Project Server 2007. I haven't had much luck with OLAP cubes. Hence I'm trying to retrieve project data first. Which is where I am stuck.

I am trying to do one of the following. I would appreciate it I could get feedback on which is the best way? Also relating to specific questions I had:

- SQL query the Project Server published database: I'm not sure what the connection string would be? Also do I use SQL Server to query? Any tutorial would be helpful.
- Project Server Interface (PSI) / Project Web Services (PWS): How do I create a an application/script that accesses data from Project Server? I know I need to include ProjectWebServices assembly. Do I need to use the Project Server 2007 SDK for this?

I'm sorry, if some of my questions are trivial. This is the first time I am dealing with Project Server and couldn't find a lot of content about Project Server 2007. If there's a better way anyone knows of, please let me know.

Thanks in advance!!!

Comment: This is a bit broad.  Can you narrow it down to the *specific* question you have?

Comment: @RobertHarvey: How do I establish a connection with the Published Project Server database? And download all projects with their milestones?